# Retrofit arrayadapter with Pojo

Tags: java, android, json, android-arrayadapter, retrofit

I have problem with array. I have to take answer from Retrofit and show this in Listview.

Server give answer:

```
{"message":"Welcome in room 3","roomNumber":"3","questions":[{"type":"trueFalse","id":1,"answer":true},{"type":"oneChoice","id":2,"answer":"A"},{"type":"multiChoice","id":3,"answer":"A,B,C"},
```

My Retrofit :

```
@GET("/room/{nr}")
void enterToRoom(@Path("nr") String RoomNr, Callback <Question> cb);
```

My first Pojo class:

```
public class GetQuestionJSON {
private String message;
private String roomNumber;
private List<Question> questions = new ArrayList<Question>();
private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String,Object>();

get/set
....
}
```

My second Pojo class:

```
public class Question {
private String type;
private Integer id;
private String answer;
public Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String,Object>();

get/set
...
}
```

And My Retrofit answer:

```
    RestClient.get().enterToRoom(RoomNumber,new Callback<Question>() {
        @Override
        public void success(Question question, Response response) {


        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {

        }
    });
```

In logs I see Retrofit answer but i don't know how I can use it for create listview.

Thanks for help!!

Comment: Are you getting an error? If so, please show the stack trace.

If you are not getting an error, but are just asking how to display a list of Question objects in an ListView, then please don't confuse the question with all of the information about Retrofit, which has nothing at all to do with displaying a list of objects in a ListView. If the latter is the case, then what have you tried? Have you read the ListView documentation?

Comment: Your "Question" object has a Java a object with your information, you can access all properties and getters/setters using plain Java accessors. Lists and Hasmaps needs to be iterated, but again, all plain Java procedures. If you are reaching the "success" callback, yo can pass from there your object to the Adapter constructor and work data there to build your item views. After that bind the Adapter to a ListView (or better, a RecyclerView) and that's all.

Comment: you should pass `GetQuestionJSON` instead of `Question` in your Calback and then retrieve this Question from GetQuestionJSON.